# Firebase - Multi-location updates method deprecated, what now?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I had some apps that used the multi-location update method as below:

```
const updates = [];
updates['/location1'] = data;
updates['/location2'] = data2;

firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Yet, as I'm developing a new app, I got the following message:

`FIREBASE WARNING: Passing an Array to Firebase.update() is deprecated. Use set() if you want to overwrite the existing data, or an Object with integer keys if you really do want to only update some of the children.`

With no real info anywhere about how to perform multi-location atomic updates anywhere, and the docs are still with the old method. Chaining `then()` is not a good idea, as it would be a nightmare to rollback.

Any clues and/or information on new multi-location updates methods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't even know you *could* pass an array. You should instead pass an object:

```
const updates = {}; // this line is different
updates['/location1'] = data;
updates['/location2'] = data2;

firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

The array syntax we use for setting properties works on a JavaScript object too.

Comment: Well I feel slightly stupid now. Thanks for the quick answer!